# Comparison portal is allowed to copy the product descriptions from manufacturer?

Tags: copyright

For a comparison portal, that just lists and compares the products developed by others, it is allowed to copy the product description and the product tehnical details from the official website of the manufacturer?

Thank you!

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You can always contact the companies, publish where you have permission, and write "company refused permission" where you don't get permission. Users of your site can draw their conclusions.

PS. Contacting each company may be work, but it's entirely legal, avoids being sued, and doesn't require getting advice from the Internet. It also works perfectly fine with companies who don't give permission.

The alternative is asking a lawyer. Even if the lawyer tells you you can use their materials, and even if the lawyer is correct, since you are talking about "thousands" of companies, you can be sure somebody will sue you.

Comment: Do I have to contact each company ? It is a tremendous work in order to do this if we talk about a couple of thousands of companies